# Error 503 for sometime after docker container up

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which creates node js, php container and one MySql DB. Everything works fine and containers are up. But when I try to check website status it gives me error 503 for a while. Website is up after like 5 minutes. I do not see any error in docker logs. docker stats command output is attached. Memory allocation looks fine.   [image]

App docker logs, you see 4 minutes difference there.

```
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.*.*.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.*.*.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Aug 19 13:22:09.190559 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.3.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 19 13:22:09.190694 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
172.*.*.* - - [19/Aug/2020:13:26:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2327 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
172.*.*.* - - [19/Aug/2020:13:26:54 -0400] "GET /static/js/main.0c1fa848.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9534 "https://example.ai/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.39.149 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Maybe check the memory consumption..try to assign more memory to docker container

Comment: @DashrathMundkar The memory allocation looks fine. I have updated my question.

Comment: Guys any help would be appreciated......

Answer (score 0):

Docker logs does not guarantee that website is running fine, it can check the services status, but website may take some time to come UP. Try to find out how much time it takes after all the services you start manually.